# Rails / backbone: not seeing some attributes in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, backbone.js

I have a rails 4.2.1 app, utilizing the backbone-on-rails gem.  I added an attribute in a rails model Valve (tracking_history_id), migrated the db, and added ':tracking_history_id' in the valves_controller.rb file, method 'valve_params', thinking that this would make this attribute visible to my javascript browser code via a json fetch of the Valves collection.  Unfortunately, that attribute is not listed in the attributes of the Valve model in the browser.  I checked the database and the attribute is there.  I even set a default value (0) in the migration, but I do not see 'tracking_history_id' in my browser Valve collection.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem.  When adding attributes to a rails model, make sure that you add the attribute to the associated index.json.builder file.  Otherwise, any json replies built will be missing that attribute.